# Mongodb node authentication says not authorized yet logs in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have the following, & im using it to log in and do a query, so I get through `db.authenticate`, but when I do my query I get thrown:

```
MongoError: unauthorized data ns:data.data lock type:0 client:127.0.0.1] name: 'MongoError' }
```

As ridiculous as the code block below may seem with all the nesting, i guess thats javascript's only flaw.

```
Db.open(function(err, db) {     
    if(!err) {
    db.authenticate("admin", "1234", function(authdb, err) {

            if(!err) { //YAY I LOG IN!!!

              db.collection('data', function(err, collection) {
                collection.findOne({'id':'1'}, function(err, item) {
                    if(err) { //What?!? I AM logged in
                         db.close();
                         console.log(err);

                }
              }  );
            }  );
          }
        }  ); //Sad face
    }
});
```

How comes I can authenticate but I can't run the `findOne` query? If I try the same with the same user in the mongo shell it goes through.

Comment: In the code above your db is called data and your collection is also called data?  How exactly do you perform authentication and the same find in mongo shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try swapping `authdb` and `err`:

```
// WRONG
db.authenticate("admin", "1234", function(authdb, err) { ... });
// RIGHT
db.authenticate("admin", "1234", function(err, authdb) { ... });
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it, I decided to move to MongoConnect though, it seems to be far easier